# OpenApi generated Client fails during upload with java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, openapi

I am using a generated OpenAPI Client for uploading a file (~190mb) to a service.
When using the generated method, the code fails with an OutOfMemoryException.

How can I tell the OpenAPI Client to use a buffered reader/writer for the file? Is there another solution?

Log:

```
2022-02-22 22:37:45.569  INFO 1 --- [  XNIO-1 task-3] okhttp3.OkHttpClient                     : Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=b75abfd1-9ae1-4c86-b69e-e444d341b051
2022-02-22 22:37:45.570  INFO 1 --- [  XNIO-1 task-3] okhttp3.OkHttpClient                     : Content-Length: 193464281
2022-02-22 22:37:45.570  INFO 1 --- [  XNIO-1 task-3] okhttp3.OkHttpClient                     : Authorization: Basic XXX
2022-02-22 22:37:45.570  INFO 1 --- [  XNIO-1 task-3] okhttp3.OkHttpClient                     : Accept: application/json
2022-02-22 22:37:45.571  INFO 1 --- [  XNIO-1 task-3] okhttp3.OkHttpClient                     : User-Agent: OpenAPI-Generator/0.0.13/java
2022-02-22 22:37:45.744  INFO 1 --- [  XNIO-1 task-3] okhttp3.OkHttpClient                     :
2022-02-22 22:37:49.588 ERROR 1 --- [  XNIO-1 task-3] o.z.problem.spring.common.AdviceTraits   : Internal Server Error

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Code:

```
private ApiClient login() {
        ApiClient defaultClient = Configuration.getDefaultApiClient();
        defaultClient.setDebugging(true);
        defaultClient.setBasePath(this.basepath);

        // Configure HTTP basic authorization: Basic
        HttpBasicAuth Basic = (HttpBasicAuth) defaultClient.getAuthentication("Basic");
        Basic.setUsername(this.username);
        Basic.setPassword(this.password);

        return defaultClient;
    }

private void upload() {
        String filename = "file.file";
        ApiClient client = login();
        MediaApi mediaApi = new MediaApi();
        mediaApi.setApiClient(client);
        Media m = mediaApi.mediaCreate(new File(filename));
}
```

OpenApi:

```
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "title": "MediaCMS API",
    "version": "0.0.13"
  },
  "host": "localhost:8085",
  "schemes": ["http"],
  "basePath": "/api/v1",
  "consumes": ["application/json"],
  "produces": ["application/json"],
  "securityDefinitions": {
    "Basic": {
      "type": "basic"
    }
  },
  "security": [
    {
      "Basic": []
    }
  ],
  "paths": {
    "/media": {
      "post": {
        "operationId": "media_create",
        "summary": "Add new Media",
        "description": "Adds a new media, for authenticated users",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "media_file",
            "in": "formData",
            "description": "media_file",
            "required": true,
            "type": "file"
          },
          {
            "name": "description",
            "in": "formData",
            "description": "description",
            "required": false,
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "title",
            "in": "formData",
            "description": "title",
            "required": false,
            "type": "string"
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "201": {
            "description": "response description",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/Media"
            }
          },
          "401": {
            "description": "bad request"
          }
        },
        "consumes": ["multipart/form-data", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"],
        "tags": ["Media"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```